# Variable Functions

Tags: php

I'm needing to create variable function names, the code I have:

```
$list = array('testa','testb','testc');

foreach($list as $type) {

    $type = function() { 
      echo " <p>$type</p>"; 

    }; 

}
```

But I keep getting "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in functions.php on line 69"

I had it working on my local server, but when I uploaded it, I get that error.  Any ideas?

Comment: What is the PHP version on the remote server? **Edit:** That said your code doesn't make sense to me. Do you want to create variable named functions, or anonymous ones? If the earlier, you should be using `create_function()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code looks like valid PHP **5.3**.

But it's not valid PHP **5.2** : [**anonymous functions**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) are one of the things added by PHP 5.3.

I' guessing your development environment is using PHP 5.3, and your server is working with PHP 5.2.

As a sidenote, not sure what you're exactly trying to do, but if you just want to display what's in your array, you could simply use :

```
foreach($list as $type) {
    echo " <p>$type</p>";
}
```

There's two strange thing in your code :

- you are using the same `$type` variable as the current element of the `foreach` loop, and for the anonymous function.
- And you are not importing the `$type` variable inside your anynomous function -- you should, to be able to use it, echoing it.

Answer (score 0):

Update php on your production server to 5.3.x